# How do I set the value of option element to the ordering?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a select element which I'm populating with s from a database.
So the code looks something like this:

```
<select name="fruitsOption" id="fruitsOptionId" ngModel #fruitRef="ngModel">
  <option *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">{{fruit}}</option>
</select>
```

I need to set the **value** attribute of **option** to their indices.
For example, if the list is Mango, Apple, Orange, the net effect after *ngFor would be like this:

```
<option value="0">Mango</option>
<option value="1">Apple</option>
<option value="2">Orange</option>
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

PS: I ultimately want to know the index of the selected element in my typescript file after the form is submitted, because I have another array with 1-to-1 correspondence to the **options** list.

I have tried this in my typescript file:

```
i = document.getElementById("fruitOptionsId").selectedIndex
```

but that doesn't work (says there is no such property).

I also tried this:

```
<option *ngFor="let i in fruits" value="i">{{fruits[i]}}</option>
```

but this throws the error **"Cannot bind to ngForIn"** or something like that

Comment: See my updated answer for a working example

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an index on the loop then you set that value to be in the value tag...

I have created an example here for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-icfc1n

Here is a copy of what you should have in your template.

```
<select name="fruitsOption" id="fruitsOptionId" ngModel #fruitRef="ngModel">
  <option *ngFor="let fruit of fruits; let i = index;" value="{{i}}">{{fruit}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index in your `ngFor` like so:

```
*ngFor="let fruit of fruits; let i = index"
```

You can then set the value using

```
<option [value]="i">{{fruit}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<select name="fruitsOption" ngModel #fruitRef="ngModel (change)="log(fruitRef.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let fruit of fruits;let i = index" [value]="i">{{fruit}}</option>
</select>

{{fruitRef.value}}
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iiuygr)

> I have add `(change)="log(fruitRef.value)"` and  `{{fruitRef.value}}` just for testing